# Differentiate between PendingIntents sent by Notification actions

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm fairly new to Android development, and working on an app that relies on putting some yes/no questions in a notification. I'll be using four PendingIntent's:

- Delete intent: to remember that the question was dismissed
- Content intent: to open an Activity offering the same question
- Intent on action 1: To answer yes
- Intent on action 2: To answer no

What I'm looking for is the best way to tell the listening service which answer was given, without having to define extra actions for them. I don't like to litter my manifest with a bunch of over specific intent filters.

Obviously, setting extras on the intent won't work - that will still make the framework see them as pretty much the same intent.

A solution that gives me the functionality I'm looking for would be to use

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("answer://yes"));
```

and

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("answer://no"));
```

But I don't think this is what the intent data is meant for.

What I would like to know is if anybody knows a better solution, or could provide any arguments in favour or against my current approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Obviously, setting extras on the intent won't work - that will still make the framework see them as pretty much the same intent.

It will work, if you use a unique integer for the second parameter to your `PendingIntent` factory method call. You indicate that these trigger "the listening service", so I assume that you are using `getService()` on `PendingIntent` as your factory method.

Also, I suggest removing the `<intent-filter>` entirely from the `<service>`, and just use extras plus the unique `PendingIntent` identifier as noted above. If you insist upon using an `<intent-filter>`, please mark the service as not exported (`android:exported="false"`). [Exported services relying upon implicit `Intent`s are at risk of being spoofed](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/09/26/android-exported-service-mitm-attacks.html), which is why the L Developer Preview no longer allows implicit `Intent`s with `bindService()`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sure that in a couple of years, when Googling my own name, I'll come across this question again and feel stupid for asking ;-). But today, I'm just happy to have found a solution.